# Cannot get index buffers to draw a square in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl-3, opengl-4

I'm definitely doing something extremely rookie here, but I simply cannot draw a square with index buffers. I'm following the intructions in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXNMC1YAxVQ). But I just don't get the expected output.

If I comment out one of the vertices in the array, it draws second triangle. Also, the `drawElement()` call seems to be working as intended as there is definitely linking between ELEMENT_ARRAY and ARRAY_BUFFER in my code, but I cannot get a square for the life of me. I checked and rechecked my code a lot. Does anyone know what I might be missing? Here's my code:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

#define print(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source) {

    // returns an empty shader object of type specified
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);

    // because one of the arguments requires a double pointer
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    // Replaces(in this case writes) the source code of a shader object
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, nullptr);

    // Compiles the shader
    glCompileShader(shader);

    // Finds compile status of shader
    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = new char[length];

        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, message);
        print("Failed to compile shader");
        std::cout << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") <<   std::endl;

        glDeleteShader(shader);
        return 0;
    }

    return shader;

}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const  std::string& fragmentShader) {

// All shaders must be attached to a program object before executed. This     returns an empyty program object
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();

    // get shaders
    unsigned vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    // Attaches the shader to the program
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    // creates shader executables
    glLinkProgram(program);

// validates success/failure/performance of program. stores in program's log
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        print("Error");
    }

    float positions[8] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, // 0
         0.5f, -0.5f, // 1
        -0.5f,  0.5f, // 2
         0.5f,  0.5f  // 3
    };

    unsigned int indices[6] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    // Assigns a memory to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
    unsigned int triangleBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);

    // Fills in data to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER memory
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Defines where positions are located in GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and how to draw them configurations
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    // Enables this vertex to be drawn using glDrawArrays().
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    // Shader programs in GLSL
    std::string vertexShader =
        // opengl version 3.3
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        // select vertex attribute 0. vec4 because gl_Position requires vec4 argument. vertex shaders are 'in'
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
        // opengl version 3.3
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        // select vertex attribute 0. vec4 because color requires vec4 argument. fragment shader have 'out'
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        // colors in graphics are usually in 0-1 range. RGBA
        "   color = vec4(0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    // generate index buffers
    unsigned int ibo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // Use Shaders
    unsigned int shaderProgram = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general your code is fine, but the specification of the vertex array buffer size is wrong. The 4 verex coordinates

```
float positions[8] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.5f };
```

consists of 8 floats, not of 6.

This means you have the sie of the vertex array is `8*sizeof(float)`. Change your code like this:

```
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    8 * sizeof(float), // <----- 8 instead of 6
    positions,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Note, you can use the [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator to determine the size of the array in bytes:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

In c++ I would prefer something like this:

```
const std::vector<float> positions{ -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,  0.5f };
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.size()*sizeof(positions[0]), positions.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! I have no clue why I didn't allocate the space for the last coordinate. Also quick followup question, when you write positions.data(), is it passed by reference?

Comment: @Advait The return type of `positions.data()` is `float*`. `vector::data` returns a pointer to the data buffer.